# texto linkados e sublinhados no edge

Tags: link

Olá, estou editando umas páginas em C#, e tenho uma página de validação onde serão listados algumas opções de radiobuttons com os dados para confirmação.
O problema é que quando é listados números de CPF eles ficam linkados e sublinhados no Edge.

Já usei o `text-decoration:none;` em todas as tags mas só funciona em um dos radiobutton.

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

```
<section>
  <div class=" container opcoes2">
     <table style="color:#464a51; text-decoration:none;">
        <tr >
          <td style="text-align:left; color:#464a51;text-decoration:none;" ><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdOpcao1" GroupName="Opcao" ForeColor="#464a51" Font-Size="14" style="text-decoration:none;"/></td>

</tr>

   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left; color:#464a51;text-decoration:none;" "><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdOpcao2" GroupName="Opcao" ForeColor="#464a51" Font-Size="14" style="text-decoration:none;" /></td>

</tr>

   <tr>

      <td style="text-align:left; color:#464a51;text-decoration:none;"><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdOpcao3" GroupName="Opcao" ForeColor="#464a51" Font-Size="14" style="text-decoration:none;" /></td>

</tr>

     <tr>

        <td style="text-align:left; color:#464a51;text-decoration:none;"><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdOpcao4" GroupName="Opcao" ForeColor="#464a51" Font-Size="14" style="text-decoration:none;" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</asp:PlaceHolder>

</div><!--opcoes-->                  
</section>
```

Comment: Camila, poste seu código completo para ficar mais fácil de identificar. Esses radios tem labels vinculados a eles para exibir o texto? No exemplo, você está setando o `text-decoration:none` direto no radio e não na tag de texto

Comment: Uma dica, poste sempre seu código [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/), clique em "Save" e poste o link da URL, te garanto que dessa forma você receberá sempre respostas  rápidas.

Comment: Valeu Jorge!!https://jsfiddle.net/2jvk3o5x/

Comment: Minha grande dificuldade é que o labels não ficam explícitos no código, apenas a chamada do c#

Comment: No caso, é preciso saber aonde está escrito esses textos para então pegar a classe/id e declarar a regra no css. Faz o seguinte, inspecione esse elemento na página e veja o elemento que  está escrito o texto e pegue a classe  e aplique a regra no css. Se tiver dificuldade, poste o print aqui nos comentários.

Comment: é, ta vindo dentro de um link, mostra a saída que aparece no navegador, o compilado

Comment: O !importante também não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Camila, como mencionado acima, é preciso saber aonde está escrito esses textos para então pegar a classe/id e declarar a regra no css. Possivelmente está vindo dentro de um link, faça o seguinte no css: `.opcoes2 table a {  text-decoration: none;}` e veja o resultado.

Comment: Usei esse css, mas não deu certo                                                .opcoes2 label {
            
            text-decoration:none;
        }

Comment: Pode ser que tenha alguma outra regra sobrescrevendo essa,tente acrescentar o `important` . Faça assim: `opcoes2 table label { text-decoration:none !important; }`

Comment: Já tentei também porém não funciona